# How to bubble sort a string array?

Tags: c#, string, sorting

```
public void BubbleSortArrayString(string[] letters) //change here
{
    bool swap;
    string temp; //change this too

    do
    {
        swap = false;

        for (int index = 0; index < (letters.Length - 1); index++)
        {
            if (letters[index] > letters[index + 1]) //if first number is greater then second then swap
            {
                //swap

                temp = letters[index];
                letters[index] = letters[index + 1];
                letters[index + 1] = temp;
                swap = true;
            }
        }

    } while (swap == true);
}
```

I have managed to bubble sort a decimal but I'm suck with a string, I have a text file with months in it and I need to sort it in alphabetical order. I get the error:

> operator > cannot be applied to type string and string

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: FYI: `== true` is unnecessary since it is just evaluating whether your boolean value equals another boolean value to return a boolean value, since you already have a boolean value to start with you can just use that (`while(swap)`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [string.Compare(x,y)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkcaxw5y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) instead of `<`, which returns 0 if the string are equal, otherwise an integer that indicates their relative position in the sort order

```
    for (int index = 0; index < (letters.Length - 1); index++)
    {
        if (string.Compare (letters[index], letters[index + 1]) < 0) //if first number is greater then second then swap
        {
            //swap

            temp = letters[index];
            letters[index] = letters[index + 1];
            letters[index + 1] = temp;
            swap = true;
        }
    }
```

If you want to ignore case during the comparison, you should use `string.Compare (letters[index], letters[index + 1], true)`

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `String.CompareOrdinal` for strings. Also it would be better if you invert your `if` statement to reduce nesting. Like this:

```
if (String.CompareOrdinal(letters[index], letters[index + 1]) >= 0) continue;                    
temp = letters[index];
letters[index] = letters[index + 1];
letters[index + 1] = temp;
swap = true;
```

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/af26w0wa(v=vs.110).aspx):

> This method performs a case-sensitive comparison using ordinal sort rules. For more information about word, string, and ordinal sorts, see System.Globalization.CompareOptions. To perform a case-insensitive comparison using ordinal sort rules, call the Compare(String, String, StringComparison) method with the comparisonType argument set to StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase.